# Does Boot Repair work for reinstalling GRUB on a UEFI dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

The GRUB menu at start has disappeared (UEFI ubuntu + windows 10 dual boot) and I can't access Ubuntu since Windows 10 starts automatically.

But I can boot from USB Live. Does Boot Repair work on UEFI systems?

In the official guide of Boot Repair it isn't mentioned, and in another guide seems like it does NOT work in UEFI systems.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Homepage](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) it's also for UEFI:

```
and much more ! (UEFI, SecureBoot, RAID, LVM, Wubi, filesystem repair...)
```

Actually, i would just give it a try, just use the [boot repair disc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/).

Comment: Why you say to use the CD? Isn't the same to run a Live USB with Ubuntu and download it from the terminal and then run it? Thank You

Comment: Actually, it's the same. Do as you want.

Comment: One caveat is that Boot Repair *must* be run from a system that's booted in the same boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI) as the target system to be repaired. That is, to repair an EFI-based installation, you *must* boot an EFI-mode emergency disk. The Ubuntu installer can boot in either mode, so if you use that, you must know how to control the boot mode. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#managing) for more on this subject.